# An error occurred while running subprocess npm. ionic start

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, npm, ionic4

I try to start a new ionic project. I did those steps

1.npm install -g @ionic/cli

2.ionic start

and I got those errors related to npm. I searched but could not find a solution.

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY: sha512-F4TxbIf2Zho1u0gkwk7pMZkuAOcjie2Ifj9Txahek0JAUamP58o+0YUlXp2xApo68CRZSFS4nMA5h897G2Q93A== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-F4TxbIf2Zho1u0gkwk7pMZkuAOcjie2Ifj9Txahek0JAUamP58o+0YUlXp2xApo68CRZSFS4nMA5h897G2Q93A== but got sha512-T7rpJR5srgZoHOMh8Kv1DDE6mbnW43SNUk9aRhPXGCfF2iJZoTEItjVYHC/gvtncRQCksb8Tk6f72HLaB6la0A==. (50573 bytes)
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://npm.community

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-05-05T06_02_58_568Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

Answer (score 6):

1. Delete package-lock.json file from your project, if it is created.
2. Check your npm version using

   ```
    npm -v
   ```
3. If your npm version is 5 and above. Then run the following command:

   ```
    npm cache verify
   ```
4. Then run your install command

   ```
    npm install -g @ionic/cli
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are having the same issue.

I found a solution for this. Go to your terminal and run

`npm cache clean --force` or `remove` npm-cache folder manually from `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming`

And then run `ionic start` again